# Netsupport School Tutor Interfering with Browser

Tags: windows, google-chrome, firefox, web, browser

I recently install netsupport school tutor v11. All my browsers stopped working after installation. Any solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’ve found it. It was a dll named “NSSWebHook.dll” that was interfering with my browsers. Goto safe mode and delete that dll.